# Selecting listview row by clicking it. asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been working for two days trying to make a listview thats poulated by an sql database selectable by clicking the desired row.  I am using the listview because I can easily format it using css. My application has several dashboards that will have several of these listviews for selecting quotes, orders, invoices etc.  I got it working pretty much except for some reason the first row is not selectable.  The second row is selectable and when selected indicates index 1 was selected.  I need all the rows selectable and index 0 or row one when you try to select it nothing happens I will include the code I am using.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //string[] Item = new string[2];
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    var myConnection = Connection.GetConnection();
    var Sql = "select Invoice_Id, Description, Balance from BalanceDue where Vendor_Num =101";
    var Command = new SqlCommand(Sql, myConnection);
    myConnection.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter(Command);
    ada.Fill(dt);
    //var reader = Command.ExecuteReader();
    ListView1.DataSource = (dt);
    ListView1.DataBind();
}

protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        Button btn = e.Item.FindControl("Button1") as Button;
        string script = this.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(btn, "", true);
        Panel p = e.Item.FindControl("Panel1") as Panel;
        p.Attributes.Add("onclick", script);
    }
}

protected void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, ListViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
}

protected void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblBad.Text = ListView1.SelectedIndex.ToString(); //just a label I use to see selected index
    lblBad.Visible = true;
}
```

aspx:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Invoice_Id"
    OnItemDataBound="ListView1_ItemDataBound"
    OnSelectedIndexChanging="ListView1_SelectedIndexChanging" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table class="body-cell-316">
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: left">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDesc" runat="server">Desc.</asp:LinkButton>
                </th>
                <th style="text-align: left">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBalance" runat="server">Balance</asp:LinkButton>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>

    <SelectedItemTemplate>
        <tr style="">
            <td>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblIdDesc"><%#Eval("Description") %></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblBalance"><%#Eval("Balance") %></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </SelectedItemTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
            <table class="body-cell-316">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblIdDesc"><%#Eval("Description") %></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblBalance"><%#Eval("Balance") %></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" CommandName="Select" runat="server" Text="Button" Visible="false" />
                </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```